# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - Python/Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to simply display data from my database in Django. I am getting the following error;
[Syntax Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYTMl.png)

My code in views.py is as follows;

```
def InputDisplay(request):
input_info = Input.objects.all()

args = {"input_detail" : input_info}

print args
return render_to_response('Project/display.html', args, 
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My if statement in display.html;

```
{% block head %}

<title> Display Measurements</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

      <h1> Input Details </h1>
      {% for detail in input_detail %}
        {{ detail.id }}
        {{ detail.waist }}
        {{ detail.height }}
      {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: looks like you are using python3 . print args is not supported. Use an ide - it should tell you about such errors

Comment: @karthikr Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 print args # python 2
```

to

```
print(args) # python 3
```

in python 3 `print` statements have to be inside `()`